# Variable in setter name of ORM EntitySave

Tags: hibernate, orm, coldfusion

I am trying to loop over some values to insert data into a DB using ColdFusion ORM.

I am having issues getting the syntax right. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
    <cfscript>

        var tn = 'CompanyName';

        transaction{

            newComp = EntityNew("company");

                newComp.set & tn &('ABC Comp');

            EntitySave(newComp);                                                

        }               

    </cfscript>
```

For simplicity of this question I am just using a single variable. The actual code loops through an array of data but if I can just figure out how to do it with a variable I can handle the rest.

I have tried a bunch of ways of doing this but I cannot get the syntax right.

Is this possible?

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like so far my options are to rewrite everything tag based and use cfinvoke or keep it in cfscript and use evaluate(). I know there have been issues with evaluate() in the past but I would love some feedback on whether it is a bad idea to use it in this situation?

Comment: If you want to stick with the script based approach, using evaluate will be the way to go. Even in the very popular FW/1 framework evaluate is used for the populate() method. So I think it couldn't be *that* wrong in your case. There is also very little documentation about why to avoid evaluate, most are in terms of performance. But cfinvoke isn't as fast as direct function calls, either. You might also find some additional useful information [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1320-ColdFusion-CFInvoke-Eliminates-The-Need-For-Evaluate-When-Dynamically-Executing-User-Defined-Functions.htm).

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I think I am going to use evaluate() for now and then maybe rewrite it to invoke when Zeus comes out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
evaluate( 'newComp.set#tn#( "ABC Comp" )' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. That works but I've always read to not use evaluate(). Is this a time where using it is the best option?

Comment: Your are right. You should avoid to use evaluate() as much as possible. Almost all instances of evaluate() can usually be replaced by using structure syntax. But when you chose/need making dynamic calls to persistent setters and getters, there is no other syntax to create this call. Using evaluate() should be a red flag anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid evaluate by using the cfinvoke tag:

```
<cfset tn = "CompanyName">
<cftransaction>
<cfset newComp = EntityNew("company")>
<cfinvoke component="#newComp#" method="set#tn#">
      <cfinvokeargument name="#tn#" value="ABC Corp">
</cfinvoke>
</cftransaction>
```

A little more on its use in the example [here](http://www.samfarmer.com/blog/index.cfm/2010/3/10/infinite-entities-cfgrid-and-one-cfc-to-handle-the-data)

The next version of ColdFusion will bring [invoke to script.](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/12/22/ColdFusion-Zeus-POTW--Extra-edition-again)

Comment: Thanks Sam. That is an option but I have all of my ORM transactions in cfscript. It will be nice when 10 comes out but I am not sure what to do in the mean time. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe write a method into your model that makes acceptance of 'dynamic' state part and parcel of its API, such as:

```
component {
  function setState( Struct state ){
    var key = 0;
    for ( key in state )
    {
      variables[ key ] = state[ key ];
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in your calling code, pass it a struct:

```
newComp = EntityNew( 'Company' );
state = {};
state[ tn ] = 'ABC Comp';
newComp.setState( state );
```

We do this commonly within our constructors, allowing us to do things in one shot, similar to Groovy and some other languages:

```
var chuck = new Contact( { firstName = "Chuck", lastName = "Taylor" });
```